# What does "if [ -e $name ]" mean? Where $name is a path to a directory

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

In the `if [ -e $name ]`, what condition check is `-e`?
`$name` is a variable of a path to a directory.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-e` returns true if the target exists. Doesn't matter if it's a file, pipe, special device, whatever. The only condition where something may exist, and `-e` will return false is in the case of a broken symlink.

For example:

```
$ ln -s foo bar

$ [ -e foo ]; echo $?
1

$ touch bar

$ [ -e foo ]; echo $?
0
```

In bash you can do `help test` to see what test options you have.

---

`[` is usually part of your shell. In bash the options and behaviors are defined by bash. It is also kind of a synonym for `test`. In bash you can do `help test` to see all the options it supports.
The only real difference between `[` and `test` should be that `[` requires a `]` after your arguments, whereas `test` does not. They otherwise work the same, `[ -e foo ]` is equivalent to `test -e foo`.

There is also `/usr/bin/[` for shells which do not have `[` built in. There is no man page for this though. But there is also a `/usr/bin/test`, and my system does have a `man test` which covers the options. I haven't tested, but I'd bet all the options supported by `/usr/bin/test` work on `/usr/bin/[`.

Comment: `[` and `test` are indeed the same program (and the POSIX spec requires them to be). Someone in the dim recesses of time thought that providing a synonym for `test`--right down to the required but unused `]` argument--was a good idea, but it's just been a source of confusion for countless beginners who think the `[` and `]` really *are* shell syntax.