# What does if [ -r "$1" ] ; mean?

Tags: shell, test

I am relatively new to shell (just now the basics of it). I am trying to make sense of a script in order to fix a bug and I stumble upon something that I can't find an answer through Google(probably not googling the right stuff).

```shell
if [ -r "$1" ] ;
```

I am very familiar with control flow, I also know the `$1` is the argument passed on to the script. What I have no idea is the actual expression that we are evaluating: `-r`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Related: [What does “if \[ -e $name \]” mean? Where $name is a path to a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127743/what-does-if-e-name-mean-where-name-is-a-path-to-a-directory)

Comment: At a bash prompt, type `help if` then `help [` then `help test`

Comment: It's a check to see if a filename (in parameter #1 of the script) exists, and is Readable by the current process. Read `man bash test`. "`[`" is a synonym for `/bin/test`.

Comment: @waltinator, `[` is a synonym for the [**builtin** `test`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-test)

Answer (score 8):

That runs the `[` command with a `-r` operator and the contents of the first positional parameter (or an empty string if no positional parameters are set) as the operand of the `-r` operator (and a closing `]` for symmetry).

The `[` command is builtin in all Bourne-like shells (and `fish`). So its documentation is generally found in the corresponding shell manual. It's also known as `test`.

Depending on your shell, try:

- `info zsh test`
- `info bash '['`
- `fish -c 'help test'`
- or `man ksh` / `man dash`... for those shells that don't have an info page.

(beware on some systems, one needs to install a `bash-doc` or `zsh-doc` package for the documentation in `info` format to be available for those shells).

Systems also generally have a standalone `[` or `test` command with a similar interface which can be used from other types of shells or from things that are not shells and don't use a shell to run commands (such as `env`, `find -exec`...). That one's documentation can be found at `info test` or `man test` (possibly `man '['` as well).

Specifically, the `-r` operator is to test whether the process running the `[` command (the shell in those where `[` is builtin)  has permission to open a given file for *reading*. If true, the `[` command returns with a *success* exit status, in which case the `if` statement executes the `then` part.

That would be the equivalent of `access(argv[1], R_OK)` in C.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak, as I said, `info test` on a GNU system gives you the manual for GNU coreutils `test`, not for the `test` builin of `bash` (the GNU shell). You'd need `info bash test` for the `test` builtin of bash.

Answer (score 4):

The `-r` asks: does the user have read permission for the file identified by the `$1` operand?

[The POSIX specification of the `test` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) contains the list of all standard operators.

Some of them are:

```
-e file exists
-f file is a regular file (not a directory or device file)
-s file is not zero size
-d file is a directory
-b file is a block device
-c file is a character device
-p file is a pipe
-L file is a symbolic link
-S file is a socket
-t file (descriptor) is associated with a terminal device
-r file has read permission (for the user running the test)
-w file has write permission (for the user running the test)
-x file has execute permission (for the user running the test)
```